# what is the point of the coreutils program 'yes'?

Tags: linux, gnu-coreutils

All it does is repeat the first argument over and over?

Is this just some kind of quirky 'Easter egg' or is there a use to it. The man page is sparse to say the least.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line/338860#338860

Answer (score 7):

Some programs, e.g. [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) with its `-ok` option, or [rm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html) with its `-i` option, etc.... are asking yes/no questions. Some scripts might use these programs with these options.

So it is *sometimes* convenient to pipe the output of `yes` into these programs or scripts.

<sup>So the answer is that sometimes (but quite rarely) `yes` is useful. I'm probably using it about once or twice a year.</sup>

BTW, it might perhaps be useful in your own scripts or piping commands. It might also be useful for benchmarking purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Program yes is used for testing / learning
I used it for example in school when we learned about killing processes
It is fastest way to use infinite loop :D

Answer (score 1):

Laying a pattern down: `yes > /dev/sdaX` is fewer keystrokes than `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdaX`

It doesn't run faster. Sometimes I don't care.

Answer (score 1):

Rarely used to input "yes" or "no" to interactive programs

More often used to generate patterns for testing or whatever:

```
yes | head -n10 > 10lines.txt
yes 0 | sed '1~2s/0/1/' # generate 1,0,1,0,... infinite clock
yes 'UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU' | tr -d '\n' > /dev/to/overwrite  # with alternating bits
```

Answer (score 0):

use it to default an answer. I.e

yes | RM *.exe